# How I publish a message using rosjs

Tags: rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you help me to publish a simple message using rosjs.
Iam struggling to publish a simple button(in html) to ros

How can I do this

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58397/how-i-publish-a-message-using-rosjs/) by [suhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/4411/suhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming you have everything installed, take a look at the [rosjs wiki](http://ros.org/wiki/rosjs), it shows you how to get started with a publisher/subscriber and service call.

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I don't know which version of rosbridge you are using. The up-to-date version of rosbridge is available in groovy and fuerte. Check out rosbridge_suite instead of rosbridge.

Please follow https://github.com/RobotWebtools/rosjs

example directory should give you an idea of how to do things.

--
Jihoon Lee(Yujin Robot)

---

Originally posted by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) with karma: 634 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1